# Why is this c++ namespace giving me grief?

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

First off, my app has a file named `Android.hpp`. This is part of the [tmxlite](https://github.com/fallahn/tmxlite) library. Compiling tmxlite on windows works fine. However, when I move the code to android studio and compile it (with the NDK), I get an error.

`Android.hpp`:

```cpp
/*********************************************************************
Matt Marchant 2016
http://trederia.blogspot.com

tmxlite - Zlib license.

This software is provided 'as-is', without any express or
implied warranty. In no event will the authors be held
liable for any damages arising from the use of this software.

Permission is granted to anyone to use this software for any purpose,
including commercial applications, and to alter it and redistribute
it freely, subject to the following restrictions:

1. The origin of this software must not be misrepresented;
you must not claim that you wrote the original software.
If you use this software in a product, an acknowledgment
in the product documentation would be appreciated but
is not required.

2. Altered source versions must be plainly marked as such,
and must not be misrepresented as being the original software.

3. This notice may not be removed or altered from any
source distribution.
*********************************************************************/

#ifndef ANDROID_INC_HPP_
#define ANDROID_INC_HPP_
#ifdef __ANDROID__

#include <string>
#include <sstream>

#include <cstdlib>

namespace std
{
    template <typename T>
    std::string to_string(T value)
    {
        std::ostringstream os;
        os << value;
        return os.str();
    }
}

#define STOI(str) std::strtol(str.c_str(), 0, 10)
#else
#define STOI(str) std::stoi(str)

#endif // __ANDROID__
#endif // ANDROID_INC_HPP_
```

The error:

```
In file included from E:\max\android_libs\tmxliteOG\tmxlite\src\FreeFuncs.cpp:28:
In file included from E:\max\android_libs\tmxliteOG\tmxlite\include\tmxlite\FreeFuncs.hpp:54:
E:\max\android_libs\tmxliteOG\tmxlite\include\tmxlite\detail\Android.hpp:37:11: error: expected '{'
```

Why is this happening? I was under the impression that this was how namespaces were supposed to be declared and I don't see what is wrong with it. I mean, I didn't even write the code :-).
help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std

Comment: The file compiles on its own: https://godbolt.org/z/qb8oz6, the problem is likely elsewhere

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. We don't need the copyright blurb, and we don't need to dig into the #include stack. The error is on line `namespace std` so you can create a small program that tests just a declaration like this.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. actually removing the copyright notice would not be compliant with the code licence

Comment: @AlanBirtles When you **create a small program that tests just a declaration like this** you are not creating a "derivative work" of the original code.

Comment: The `std` namespace is special.   With a very few specific exceptions, declaring anything in namespace `std` gives undefined behaviour (except as part of the implementation).    You (or the authors of the library) are fortunate if it works under windows.   Porting such code between implementations (compilers, standard libraries, or host systems) is a good way for problems to emerge, since different implementations are free to deal with instances of undefined behaviour differently.